# How to remove a breakpoint in delve

Tags: debugging, go

I've just installed [delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve) to debug go code. I tried to add a few breakpoints but I couldn't find how to delete breakpoints. How do you remove a breakpoint you've set?

Answer (score 3):

find existing endpoints:

```
breakpoints
```

It should output something like this:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4ad817 for main.getChange() ./main.go:22 (1)
```

Now we can delete the **breakpoint 1**

```
clear 1
```

If you are in the middle of a debugging process you may need to restart first with the r or restart command and then execute the clear command.

You can also use **clearall** to delete multiple breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to remove a breakpoint in delve.

You can use the clear NUMBER or clearall

Examples:

Clear the break point 2.

```
clear 2
```

Clear all the break point.

```
clearall
```

In addition, in delve you can actually enter help to get a list of commands.